# How can perform a silent uninstall with installjammer

Tags: uninstallation, silent

I am trying to get silent install and uninstall using InstallJammer.

I was able to install silently by changing   Default Install Mode to silent under platform information . But how can I specify the uninstall to be silent?

Thanks in advance,

Srirekha

Comment: For a silent install, use /s flag. You dont have to change the "default install mode".

Answer (score 2):

InstallJammer will create uninstall.exe in the root directory of the installed product. Do

```
uninstall.exe /s
```

from a command prompt for a silent uninstall.

You can see all possible options by doing:

```
uninstall.exe /?
```